# Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program even changed the jre to JDK?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

i donot know the base of problem even i searched that it could be fixed with jdk installed in eclipse but same problem, any help!!

BUILD FAILED
E:\GAP\gapvis\build.xml:32: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\GAP\gapvis\build.xml:108: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\GAP\gapvis\build.xml:172: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\GAP\gapvis\build.xml:176: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "lessc.cmd": CreateProcess error=2, Le fichier spécifié est introuvable

Answer (score 1):

Le fichier spécifié est introuvable means the lessc.cmd file cannot be found. Are you sure you put it in the same directory as the build.xml?

Comment: yes i think its the problem but i cannot find it though i just imported the project from Github, i need to search for it thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to add lessc.cmd to your path since it wants to execute it. If it is available on the system but eclipse ignores it you need to add that path into eclipse so it knows where it can execute it.

plan b would be to try an absolute path for lessc.cmd in your build.xml file (line 176)

Comment: what is meant by absoulute path? can you please elaborate!

Comment: lessc.cmd looks like a batch script that is either in the project or elsewhere on the system. So instead of "lessc.cmd" use the full path "c:\folder\to\this\script\lessc.cmd"